# Repeat Pytest session for multiple inputs

Tags: python, pytest

With Pytest framework I have written a number of tests.
At the beginning of the test session I have to import data from an excel file to an in-memory database and then execute tests with that data as input.
Since the import is computational intensive, I have put the excel import call in a session-scoped fixture inside conftest.py file:

```
# Session variables
def pytest_configure():
    pytest.source_file = '/test_pytest/data/data_source.xls'

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=False)
def load_file(request):
    db = my_dbmanager()
    db.DataLoad(pytest.source_file)
    return db
```

The "db" object is passed to the test fuctions in order to run its methods for extracting data from the database.

Now I would like to repeat the whole session multiple times with different excel files as input.
I thought I could wrap the pytest call inside another script and repeat the run passing the source file path to pytest with a command line argument.

I am wondering whether there are smarter methods for doing this relying on pytest functionalities.